Show that however "close" to a specified operator, an invertible operator always exists
From Linear Algebra Done Right 4th edition 7F Exercise 9.
Suppose $T$ is an operator on $V$, a nonzero finite-dimensional inner product space over F (where F is either R or C). I want to show that, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an invertible operator $S$ on the same $V$ such that $0 < ||T-S|| < \epsilon$.
Normally when asking for help on textbook exercises I would provide my current progress, but I am at a lost on even how to start here. I am still trying to see a approach from all the formulas for norm of linear maps. I would like to request some hint or guidance.

Investigate $T+\epsilon I$.

$T-kI$ is not invertible iff $k$ is an eigenvalue

Thank you all. I know how to do it now. It is a bit frustrating that at times I fail to recall even the basic facts. I need to do more exercises.

Also, I would like to ask, I understand that it is undesirable to leave questions unclosed. But for textbook exercises like this should I try to answer it (if no one else did) after receiving help? Or is it actually better/fine to leave it as it is since it is afterall an exercise meant for self-practicing?

I don't think it matters a lot, but probably closing it (with answer) will save a bit more time for community.

@mihaild Ok, got it.

Take $\epsilon^{'}$ satisfying $0 < \epsilon^{'} < \epsilon$ and $-\epsilon^{'}$ is not an eigenvalue of T.
Define an operator $S = T - \epsilon^{'}I$ on $V$. Then $S$ is invertible, and $$0<||T-S||=||\epsilon^{'}I||=\epsilon^{'}||I||=\epsilon^{'}1 = \epsilon^{'} < \epsilon$$
And we are done.
